# Issues keeping widgets in window

Tags: python, tkinter

I have created a gui using tkinter that refreshes itself every one minute (in this example I refresh it faster so that I can see the problem faster). However, when it gets to about 300 or more redraws, everything comes off the canvas and goes to the upper left hand corner of the screen and stays there (to get this to 300 refreshes, I help it by resizing the window, it also happens when it just sits there). Why would it do something like this?

Any ideas on how to fix this?

This program is supposed to be able to stay open for at least a week, possibly longer, refreshing every minute.

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkFont
import ttk
import math
import time
import os
numT = 15
cellWidth = 325
from win32api import GetSystemMetrics
wWidth = GetSystemMetrics (0)
wHeight = GetSystemMetrics (1)
class GUI(Frame):
   def __init__(self, root):
      Frame.__init__(self, root)
      self.parent = root
      self.canvas = Canvas(self.parent, relief=SUNKEN, background="red")
      self.entry = Frame(self.canvas, background="black", bd=1)
      self.canvas.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
      self.entry.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1, anchor="nw")
   def createMatrix(self, rows, columns):
      tContainers = 0
      for i in range(rows):
         for j in range(columns):
            container = Frame(self.entry, background="yellow")
            entry = ttk.Label(container, text="%d, %d"%(i,j))
            container.grid_propagate(False)
            container.config(width=325, height=185)               
            container.grid(column=j, row=i, padx=1, pady=1) 
            entry.grid(column=j, row=i)
            tContainers = tContainers + 1               
            if tContainers > numT:
               tContainers = tContainers - 1
               container.grid_forget()
            slaves = self.entry.grid_slaves()
      return slaves
   def resize(self, event):
      global wWidth
      global wHeight
      wWidth = event.width
      wHeight = event.height
      self.refreshWindow()
   def initWindow(self):
      self.cells = numT*cellWidth
      initWidth = self.canvas.winfo_screenwidth()
      if self.cells > initWidth:
         self.columns = (initWidth/cellWidth)
      else:
         self.columns = numT
      self.rows = float(numT)/self.columns
      self.rows = int(math.ceil(self.rows))
      self.slaves = self.createMatrix(self.rows, self.columns)
   def resizeWindow(self):
      width = wWidth
      height = wHeight
      if  self.cells > width or self.cells <= width:
         for wgt in self.slaves:
            wgt.grid_forget()
         if self.cells > width:
            self.columns = (width/cellWidth)
         else:
            self.columns = numT 
         if width < cellWidth:
            self.columns = 1         
         self.rows = float(numT)/self.columns
         self.rows = int(math.ceil(self.rows))
         self.slaves = self.createMatrix(self.rows, self.columns)
      else:
         self.slaves = self.createMatrix(self.rows, self.columns)  
   def refreshWindow(self):
      self.resizeWindow()
      self.after (500, self.refreshWindow)
   def Run(self):
      self.initWindow()
      self.canvas.bind("<Configure>", self.resize)
if __name__ == "__main__":
   root = Tk()
   root.configure(background="black")
   root.wm_minsize(750, 500)
   test = GUI(root)
   test.Run()
   root.mainloop()
```

This is as bare bones as I could get the code, without losing the major features I want it to have. The final version has many other thing, but it looks like it's this code that is giving me the issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's do a little math.

Let's say you are creating a 4x4 matrix. That's 16 areas. In each area you are creating one Frame and one Label, for a total of 32 widgets. You are doing this twice a second, and **you never destroy these widgets**. That means every second you are creating 64 widgets. After only one minute you end up with 3,840 widgets. After 10 minutes you have 38,400 widgets.

You say you want this to stay up for a week. That's 7 days * 24 hours in a day * 60 minutes in an hour * 60 seconds in a minute * 64 widgets per second. After a week you will have created 38,707,200 widgets. You also have a second problem, which is that you call `refreshWindow` both from an `after` event, and when the window resizes. So, every time the window resizes it starts *another* loop of widget creation, which adds an entirely new loop of widget creation. So, if your window resizes just once at the start of the week, you'll end up creating 76 million widgets. Double, triple, quadruple that if the window gets resized more than once.

The problem is that you keep creating widgets but you never destroy them, so eventually you'll run out of system resources and cause Tkinter to fail in possibly unexpected ways.  When you call `grid_forget`, you aren't destroying the widgets, you are simply removing them from view. They still exist, and they still take up memory. If you plan to never use the widgets again you should call their `destroy` method. Tkinter scales pretty well, but when you create literally millions of widgets it's reasonable to expect it to fail.

The solution is either to a) destroy widgets before creating more, or b) learn how to reuse the existing widgets. (b) is the preferred solution, as I don't see any reason why you need to destroy them and then recreate them.

Comment: Each widget needs to be refreshed and display new information every minute. I'm guessing destroying the widgets and redrawing them would be better than trying to figure out how to reuse them. Where would I destroy them?

Comment: Reusing them is trivial. Just keep a reference to each label, then do something like `label[(i,j)].configure(text="new text"')`

Comment: This is a dynamic grid that changes the positions i and j for each entry, would I be able to use `label[(i,j)]`? Also, I have 5 labels and a picture that all need to be refreshed each minute. Each yellow box holds a set of these. All the info is coming from two different files/functions: one with a list of names, and a function that lets me know status' and updates the rest of the labels. (btw, thanks for helping me out, I'm a bit new to the tkinter world)